# jquery function .submit() cannot post the data in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, submit

I have a form like this

```
<li id="li-298056">
<form id="form-298056" method="POST" action="tab_board.php">
<div class="titre_4">CAMPAGNE ANTIGONE</div>
......
<input type="hidden" value="298056" name="lot_id">
</form>
</li>
```

I use the .submit() to submit the the form

```
$('#li-298056').click(function(){
    $('#form-298056').submit();
});
```

This works well ffx. In the IE browser i cannot get the post values in the action page. It display an error 'syntext errors'.
But if i start the developpment tool of IE, and start to debug the javascript or select the li block then it works.
How to solve this?

Comment: Why are you using jquery here, why not just use a `<input type="submit" />` If its style you're worried about, use CSS to style the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known bug in IE that prevents a form from being submitted when there is no submit element inside. Try adding

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" style="display:none" />
```

to your markup and see if it works.